# Pyquery scrape a class having space in its class name

Tags: python, web-scraping, pyquery

My problem is that i have to scrape a website which has:

```
<div class="xyz tab"> blah blah </div>
```

And another div in the same website having which is as follows:

```
<div class="xyz">blah blah</div>
```

to scrape a website without space i can use this

```
pyquery('.xyz').text()
```

but for with space what should i do???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to check for both `xyz` and `tab` classes, you can use `.xyz.tab`:

```
>>> from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
>>> data = """
... <div>
...     <div class="xyz tab">test1</div>
...     <div class="xyz">test2</div>
... </div>
... """
>>> d = pq(data)
>>> print d('.xyz.tab')
<div class="xyz tab">test1</div>
```